# How can locate a specific column's value based on the selected radio button? (jquery)

Tags: jquery, html, .net, .net-4.0, aspxgridview

I am working with an ASP.Net webforms and I am having issues retrieving datagrid values that are not linked to a radio button. Basically I want to retrieve a specific column's value (lets say for example: the person's SSN) on the same row as the selected radio button using jquery. Currently the radio button is meant to retrieve the report. How would I go about doing this?  below is how datagrid is currently setup.

```html
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="content" runat="server">
    <div class="confirmation">
        <div class="row confirmation-content">
            <div class="col-sm-12" style="height: 340px; overflow-y: scroll;">
                <asp:DataGrid ID="dgReports" CssClass="table table-condensed table-striped table-bordered  grid" runat="server" PageSize="25"
                    OnItemDataBound="dgReports_ItemDataBound" DataKeyField="ReportId" OnSortCommand="dgReports_Sort" AllowSorting="True" Width="100%" AllowPaging="False"
                    AutoGenerateColumns="False">
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:TemplateColumn SortExpression="FullName" HeaderText="Borrower" HeaderStyle-CssClass="col-sm-6"
                            ItemStyle-CssClass="col-sm-6">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <input type="radio" class=" radio" name="rbJoinReport" value='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.ReportId") %>'
                                    id='<%# "rbJoinReport" + DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.ReportId").ToString() %>'
                                    onclick="OnRadioClick(this); ">
                                <label for='<%# "rbJoinReport" + DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.ReportId").ToString() %>' title=" <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.FullName") %>">
                                    <span id='<%# "rbJoinReport" + DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.ReportId").ToString() + "lbl" %>' class="borrower-name" style="max-width: 400px">
                                        <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.FullName") %>
                                    </span>
                                </label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateColumn>
                        <asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="View" ItemStyle-CssClass="col-sm-1" HeaderStyle-CssClass="col-sm-1">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:HyperLink ID="hlApplicant" Text="(View)" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.ReportId", "../ViewReport.aspx?ReportId={0}") %>' onmouseover="window.status='View Report';return true;" onmouseout="window.status='';return true;"
                                    onclick="window.open(this.href,'_blank','toolbar=no,location=no,status=no,menubar=yes,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,width=800',''); return false;">
                                </asp:HyperLink>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateColumn>
                        <asp:TemplateColumn SortExpression="boSSN" HeaderText="SSN" ItemStyle-CssClass="col-sm-2" HeaderStyle-CssClass="col-sm-2">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <span><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.boSSN") %></span>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateColumn>
                        <asp:TemplateColumn SortExpression="UserReference" HeaderText="Reference" ItemStyle-CssClass="col-sm-2" HeaderStyle-CssClass="col-sm-2">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <span><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.UserReference") %></span>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateColumn>
                        <asp:TemplateColumn SortExpression="RequestDate" HeaderText="Run" ItemStyle-CssClass="col-sm-1" HeaderStyle-CssClass="col-sm-1">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <span><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.RequestDate", "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}") %></span>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateColumn>
                    </Columns>
                </asp:DataGrid>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row   confirmation-footer">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <div class="pull-right">
                    <input type="button" value="Cancel" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger  confirmation-cancel" id="btnCancel" name="Button1">
                    <input type="button" value="Join" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary  confirmation-value" id="btnJoin" name="Button2" tabindex="1" disabled>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering your SSN is an input field, this is what you may do.

**Converted markup from asp.net data grid**

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>
<input type="text" attr="ssn"></input>
</td>
<td>
<input type="radio"></input>
</td>
</tr>
</table>

<script>
$().ready(function()
{
$('input:radio').click(function()
{
   alert($(this).parent().parent().find("input[attr=ssn]").val());
});
});
</script>
```

I've used an attribute 'attr' on the element to locate the specific field. You may also use a class or any special notation.

EDIT :

If you want to assign this to a variable :

```
var ssnField = $(this).parent().parent().find("input[attr=ssn]");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cfom5j1e/

Comment: Would I be able to assign it to a variable for later use?